# CVTRES : Fatal Error CVT1105: Cannot Seek In File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile-5.0, fatal-error

I was compiling my Windows Mobile project that is a image viewer and just when I clicked in the build button I got this error:

> CVTRES : fatal error CVT1105: cannot seek in file

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate with Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a question of too large icon file, try to use the smaller one.